# Laravel Architecture - Microservices or separate applications?

Tags: php, laravel, architecture

We are creating an ad exchange platform. Website owners can implement our tag to display ads. They can manage it on a Publisher Panel. We can manage Publishers and settings on an Admin Panel. The tags the publisher implement on their website call our API which returns the ads that will be shown. We also need an automatic monitoring-system in the backend that will monitor campaigns performance, check for fraud and make adjustments.

As we see it, we have 4 parts of the system:

There are different parts of the system:

- Admin Panel (barely any load)
- Publisher Panel (light load)
- Monitoring (medium-high load)
- Ad API (very high load)

We want to develop this project with Laravel 8.

What is the best architecture for this kind of business? 4 separate applications? Microservices? Any other recommendations?

We want to keep the system as light and scalable as possible. So the high load systems should not be slowed down by code of the low load systems.

Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the Admin Panel and the Publisher Panel to a separate application, the problem is that I think you will use the same database in all the system parts, or I'm wrong?

You could use Redis in the Monitoring and ad API parts for improving the system performance and prevent your SQL database from a high load. With Redis you can store in memory the data that your api parts needs from your database, with that you can have all the api load separated from the web application and only with the cost of the first loads of the starting queries and the subsequent queries for storing new data in memory

So use Redis as a cache for MYSQL (if it's your engine), see this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-redis-as-a-cache-for-mysql-with-php-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Correct, all systems will use the same database. Does that make it a bad idea to split them into completely different applications? What do you think of making them microservices with laravel?

Comment: @DeveloperJano Of course you could use for example Lumen for the API (or simply another Laravel application), it could be good because you will in general reduce the CPU usage of Apache/nginx whatever you use thanks to that (considerint that you put the microservices in different machines or cloud)